# Progress on Bouniakowsky's Conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Has there been any progress on the [Bouniakowsky conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BouniakowskyConjecture.html)? In particular, has anyone been able to prove something for a particular polynomial - or for a class of them?

(I can't seem to find anything, but that could be due to the fact that there seem to be many ways of spelling Bouniakowsky.)

Comment: No. It's still not known for a single polynomial of degree at least two. If it gets proved, you'll hear of it.

Comment: @KConrad: that was a silly typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It now goes by the name "Schinzel's Hypothesis H", which has a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H). A quantitative form is known as the "Bateman-Horn Conjecture", which also has a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman-Horn_conjecture).

Short answer: no progress, but better conjectures!

Comment: I figured as much. Thank you, Kevin.

Comment: Isn't H much more general than Bouniakowsky? Doesn't it deal with finite collections of polynomials, while Bouniakowsky just deals with a single polynomial?

Comment: @gerry: That's right, that's part of the "better" to which I referred. In the single polynomial situation, I think it is common to write "by Schinzel's Hyp. H, ...", while I'd never heard of Bouniakowsky's Conjecture before.